# Firestore unable to get the data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this on my firestore:

[image]

and this is how I'm retrieving the data. I simply copied it from the firebase documentation and it keeps on saying "No such document"

```
useEffect(() => {
    const Ref = firestore.collection("business").doc("business-store");
    const doc = Ref.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log("No such document!");
    } else {
      console.log("Document data:.", doc.data());
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: can you try using async await to get the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way, it should give you the result:

```
 useEffect(() => {
       firestore.collection("business").doc("business-store").get().then(doc=>{
     if (!doc.exists) {
          console.log("No such document!");
        } else {
          console.log("Document data:.", doc.data());
        }
    }).catch(error={})
       
      }, []);
```